# How can i highlight the element in div on tabbing using css

Tags: html, css

Below is my html where i have dropdowns and textboxes along with this in my webpage.The issue is when tabbing from one control to another control all the controls are getting tabbed and highlighted expect the below one.

```
<div class="cls" id="Col" onclick="Toggle(this);">Highlight me in border</div>
  <input type="button" value="Add1" id="btnAdd1" onclick="Add1();" style="width: 120px;" class="newAddNew Tab" />
 <input type="button" value="Add2" id="btnAdd2" onclick="Add2();" style="width: 120px;" class="newAddNew Tab" />
```

css

```
.Tab:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #61C5FA !important;
}
```

Comment: You could add the HTML of some other controls for comparison. The JavaScript handlers and the CSS in play could also be helpful do pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Tabbing working for input type of html but not dor div element